# Unsure what this code is doing? I want it to do the opposite of what it's actually doing

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I'm working on this project that someone else already started and I'm unsure how this part of code works, it's actually doing what I don't want it to do.

Currently when I use a select multiple and press the button it adds to the array the ones that I DIDN'T select, when I want it to add the ones I did select to the array, this array is then used as the data for a table so it's obvious it's selecting the wrong stuff.

This is the method when the button is pressed. `package_courses` is the final array that the table data is populated with.

```
addCourses() {
    const currentCourses = this.packageForm.package_courses.map((item) => item.course_id);
    const courses = this.courses.filter((item) => {
        return this.selectedCourses.indexOf(item.id) && currentCourses.indexOf(item.id) < 0
    });

    courses.forEach((course) => {
        this.packageForm.package_courses.push({
            course_id: course.id,
            course: course,
            price: 0
        });
    });
    this.selectedCourses = [];
},
```

Comment: You'll need to modify the `this.courses.filter` bit, most likely. Perhaps as simple as switching `<` for `>` or `>=`; it's hard to say without knowing the point of the code and what the data looks like.

Answer (score 1):

In the second line the `filter` method loops all items in `this.courses` and returns only those items where the statement inside returns true. `indexOf` is an array method that searches an array for the specified item and returns the position of the item in the array or -1 if the items isn't found. so I guess what you want to do is filter for courses where indexOf is *greater or equals* than/to 0, instead of less, here is your code modified.

```
addCourses() {
    const currentCourses = this.packageForm.package_courses.map((item) => item.course_id);
    const courses = this.courses.filter((item) => {
        return this.selectedCourses.indexOf(item.id) && currentCourses.indexOf(item.id) >= 0
    });

    courses.forEach((course) => {
        this.packageForm.package_courses.push({
            course_id: course.id,
            course: course,
            price: 0
        });
    });
    this.selectedCourses = [];
},
```

Comment: I tried this but then nothing gets added to the array

Comment: yea, well I think, because since the table is linked to that array when I press the button the table updates and now nothing gets added to the table

Comment: even if I remove the < 0 all the way the same thing happens, where the selected ones don't get added but the rest do

Comment: Sorry, but I don't fully understand, I would need to see more code to help you more.

Comment: what else do you want to see?

Comment: Probably how all those variables (selectedCourses, package_courses, this.courses) are assigned in the first place would help

Comment: courses is brought from the controller and just has all the courses in the db and is instanced in data `courses: [],`. 

`package_courses` is the array that the table is using for it's data, also instanced in data() `package_courses: []`,

selecedCourses is for the select and is instanced in the data() `selectedCourses: []`

Comment: `this.selectedCourses.indexOf(item.id) &&` check likely shouldn't be there.